# CSS Borders workaround

Tags: html, css

On a site I'm building I want to have a 3 coloured border [example here](http://i40.tinypic.com/2mw8lkj.jpg) for the body.

What is the easiest way to create this?

I tried the following but it didn't work out how I expected it to:

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="white">
        <div id="blue">

            <!--SITE GOES HERE-->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#red {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 16px;
    background: #CC092F;
}

#white {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 16px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

#blue{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 16px;
    background: #0C144E;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

The problem with that is the padding pushes the divs offscreen, I realise I'm going about it the wrong way… (If i use percentages i.e. 98% it obviously scales, which I do not want) but I can't think of an alternative. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your 3º line of code you have `<div id=id"blue">`. It should be `<div id="blue">`

Comment: When you have a question regarding to HTML, CSS and JavaScript and you place the code/markup language on Stackoverflow, developers appreciate a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this ([SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XRXYe/1/)):

```
<div id="red" class="site-border">
    <div id="white" class="site-border">
        <div id="blue" class="site-border">
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content {
    height: 500px;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    padding: 16px;
}
.site-border {
    width:100%;
}
#red {
    border: 16px solid #CC092F;
}
#white {
    border: 16px solid #fff;
}
#blue {
    border: 16px solid #0C144E;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scaling, you should use the below properties in your CSS, this way, the borders and paddings will be counted inside the element instead of outside as normal box model does.

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't use `position: absolute;` cuz I don't see any reason of using that over here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this css:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid navy;
  outline: 3px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 6px darkred;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BXFUk/2/